# AWS Elasticcache Memcached With Zend

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, zend-framework, memcached

We have made several API's with the zend framework but due to large data amount we have to use AWS Elasticcache

There is two types of services available **Redis** and **Mem-cached**

**Mem-cached** is suitable for my api but i have did the several research on it for php integration 
also i m so new to this environment also so i never got appropriate answer from web

So please help me to understand the Flow of Working with **AWS ElasticCache Mem-cached**

-> from where we can start

-> what Resource needed ?

-> what are the things we have to download and install

-> and to implement in Existing API url what are the things we need to change and do a code (From where we can start)

Comment: As far as I know from a code point of view you use ElasticCache in the same way as you would any memcache server. You might need to narrow your question to something other than "how do I use Zend Cache?"

Comment: zend-cache is so simple to use. just checkout docs.